# How to scale an object and change position to keep one fixed point

Tags: algorithm, unity-game-engine

Note: I am using Unity3D to accomplish this this but I am pretty sure this is a generic question.

I have an object and I want to scale it and then translate it so that when that object is scaled one specific point on the picture that I pick will stay in the same location after being scaled.

Basically, this picture:

[image]

If I am scaling an object with width w, and height h, at position (x, y) (position is the center of image) by a factor of s, how much would I have to translate it to maintain a fixed point at point (a, b).

EDIT: I forgot to mention that in Unity by default the object is scaled from the center of the object

Comment: Re: "Note: I am using Unity3D to accomplish this this but I am pretty sure this is a generic question": If nothing else, it will depend on what "scaling" means in Unity3D. Since it obviously doesn't let you specify the fixed point (or else you wouldn't be asking this question), how does it determine the fixed point to use? Will the fixed point always be (0, 0)?

Comment: The center of the object is the fixed point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Translate it by minus the position (it's now centered at the origin, scaling will be equal in all directions)
2. Translate it by the offset you want to remain unscaled
3. Scale it
4. Undo the two translations you did to start with

Technically the first two steps can be combined, if you know the offset in absolute coordinates, but usually people measure it in local coords.

Comment: I did this and it just always scales directly into the center. Just to confirm this is what I am doing:  First I subtract the position from the object moving it to the center than add the offset which is the distance of the fixed point from the center of the object (so if the center of the object is (0,0) and the fixed point is (2, 2) I translate the object by (2, 2). and then I scaled the object and then translated it -offset and then add the position.

Comment: Just wondering, does your solution still work when taking the edit I made to the problem in to consideration?

Comment: Nevermind I tried your algorithm again and it worked great! When I was undoing the two translations I used the exact same translations but turns out I had to multiply the offset by the scale factor when translating back. Thanks!